# Beef broth vs. beef stock

Tags: beef

I have a few leftover bones from prime rib  but not really enough to make much stock . I have a little extra prime rib meat left over and wondering if I can make soup stock with it too. we don't really want to eat the prime rib after making the stock either. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It isn't clear what your question is; would you clarify?

Comment: Local butchers (even some supermarket ones) will have beef bones you could buy to make a stock

Answer (score 5):

Yes, certainly, but it won't do as much good as you might expect. It takes a surprisingly large amount of meat to add significant beef flavor to beef stock.

If you want to go ahead, be sure to brown the extra meat, to get maximum umami flavor out of it. (You will want to brown the bones, too; I'd roast them in the oven.) Another way to add extra beef flavor is to throw in some ground beef, which has the nice benefit of giving up its flavor quickly.

But it might be better to throw it all in a gallon ziplock and stick it in the freezer. Keep accumulating bones, then make a potful of stock all at once. (You can keep them for months, or even longer. The biggest worry of freezing meat is freezer burn, which isn't a problem if you're just making stock.)

Comment: FWIW, the bag-and-freeze method is one that I've used for years and years (mostly with poultry, but it's the same principle) and it's a great way to keep stock on hand. You can place extra stock into ice cube trays, freeze it, and keep that in bags too.